# ¿Como alineo el texto para que este en forma de bloque en ese mismo espacio?

Tags: html, css, web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Quiero alinear el texto para que tenga forma de bloque totalmente alineado por los lados y se pueda leer bien, como puedo conseguir eso? Pego mi código actual aquí:

```
'''<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 30px;"><strong><span style="font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; color: #000000;">HERE'S YOUR DEFINITIVE PLAN TO TAKE CONTROL OF YOUR LIFE AND CREATE YOUR </span></strong></span><span style="font-size: 30px;"><strong><span style="font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif; font-style: normal; color: #000000;">MINDSET MOMENTUM!</span></strong></span></h2>
```

Listen closely... it's time for you to develop the energy, focus & motivation to achieve your goals in less time than ever before, based on neuroscience, psychology & biohacking. Join thousands of others for the 13-Week Week Mission to Becoming Unstoppable Today!
'''

Answer (score 0):

Si el efecto que esperas es que las filas queden paralelas verticalmente text-align: justify; lo hace excepto la ultima si el texto es demasiado corto para separarlo.

```
<h2 style="text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: 30px;"><strong><span style="font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; color: #000000;">HERE'S YOUR DEFINITIVE PLAN TO TAKE CONTROL OF YOUR LIFE AND CREATE YOUR </span></strong></span><span style="font-size: 30px;"><strong><span style="font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif; font-style: normal; color: #000000;">MINDSET MOMENTUM!</span></strong></span></h2>
```

Tambien puedes hacerlo manualmente y calcular cuantos caracteres ocupan una fila y comcatenar espacios entre palabras.